# Are $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$ and $\mathbb{RP}^{2n}$ diffeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I understand that they are homeomorphic but couldn't find a proof that they are diffeomorphic. If they are diffeomorphic and if the proof is simple enough, I would imagine it would look like the following:

$$\mathbb{CP}^{n}=(\mathbb{C}^{n+1}/\{0\})/{\sim}_{\mathbb{C}}\simeq(\mathbb{R}^{2(n+1)}/\{0\})/{\sim}_{\mathbb{R}^2}\simeq(\mathbb{R}^{2n}/\{0\})/{\sim}_{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{RP}^{2n} $$

where the equalities hold by definition, equivalence is diffeomorphism, and $\sim_k$ denotes the equivalence class under the multiplication by nonzero $m\in k$. The first equivalence is by the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2\simeq\mathbb{C}$, but I don't know how to prove the second equivalence. Could anybody help me?

Comment: $\Bbb R P^{2n}$ is not simply connected, so it doesn't even have the same homotopy type as $\Bbb C P^n$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a terrible misunderstanding.

Comment: @RolfHoyer: You should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From the comment above by @RolfHoyer.*

---

> I understand that they are homeomorphic but couldn't find a proof that they are diffeomorphic.

This is incorrect: $\Bbb{RP}^{2n}$ and $\Bbb{CP}^n$ are **not** homeomorphic because [$\Bbb{CP}^n$ is simply connected for all $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/869838/279515) whereas [$\Bbb{RP}^n$ is not simply connected for any $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space#Homotopy_groups). So they don't even have the same homotopy type.

Hence, $\Bbb{RP}^{2n}$ and $\Bbb{CP}^n$ are not homeomorphic and hence not diffeomorphic.