# Every holomorphic map from Complex projective line to complex torus is constant + generalization.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Here is the result:

> Every holomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}P^1$ into a complex torus is constant.

And what about a holomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}P^n$ into a complex torus?

I have no idea at the moment.. This is the exercise 2.1.4. from Huybrechts book, "Complex geometry"

Comment: For the first case use the fact the one-dimensional complex torus is a quotient of the complex line.

Answer (score 2):

Any holomorphic mapping from the complex $n$-dimensional complex projective space into a complex $m$-torus is constant.

To see this, recall the following result from the theory of covering spaces. (It essentially is Theorem 4.17. in Forster's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*.)

**Theorem.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be Hausdorff topological spaces. Let $Z$ be a simply connected, locally path connected and path connected topological space. Let $\pi\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a (not necessarily surjective) covering map. Then any continuous map $f\colon Z\rightarrow Y$ lifts to a continuous map $\hat{f}\colon Z\rightarrow X$ along $\pi$, i.e. we have $f=\pi\circ\hat{f}$.

Now, let $\Gamma\subsetneq \mathbb{C}^m$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}^m$. Let $f\colon \mathbb{CP}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m/\Gamma$ be a holomorphic mapping into the complex $m$-torus $\mathbb{C}^m/\Gamma$.
To apply above theorem to your problem, first check that the quotient map $\pi\colon \mathbb{C}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m/\Gamma$ is a covering map. For instance, you could show that the group action $\Gamma\times \mathbb{C}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m;(k,z)\mapsto k+z$ is properly discontinuous. Next, note that the complex $n$-dimensional complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is locally path connected (it is even a complex $n$-dimensional manifold) and path connected (it is the image of a path connected space under a continuous map). Additionally, convince yourself that [$\mathbb{CP}^n$ is simply connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869838/is-complex-projective-space-simply-connected).

Now, since holomorphic mappings are in particular continuous, by above theorem, there exists a continuous lift $\hat{f}\colon \mathbb{CP}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m$ of $f$ along $\pi$. We convince ourselves that $\hat{f}$ is a holomorphic mapping. To see this, let $z\in\mathbb{CP}^n$. Since $\pi$ is a covering map, it is a homeomorphism near $\hat{f}(z)$. Thus, near $\hat{f}(z)$ the quotient map $\pi$ has a local inverse, say $\pi^{-1}$. Since $\pi$ is holomorphic, this [inverse is holomorphic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44947/holomorphy-of-inverse-map). Thus, near $z$ the map $\hat{f}$ is of the form $\pi^{-1}\circ f$. Said differently, locally the map $\hat{f}$ is the composition of holomorphic mappings. Hence, the map $\hat{f}$ is holomorphic.

Next, assume for a contradiction that $\hat{f}$ was non-constant. Then there would exist $i\in\{1,\ldots m\}$ such that the holomorphic function $p_i\circ\hat{f}\colon \mathbb{CP}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ was non-constant. Here, the function $p_i\colon \mathbb{C}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ denotes the canonical projection onto the $i$-th coordinate. By the Open mapping theorem for holomorphic functions of several variables (Theorem 3.1. in Laurent-Thiébaut's *Holomorphic Function Theory in Several Variables*), the function $p_i\circ\hat{f}$ would be an open mapping. Thus, since $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is compact and $p_i\circ\hat{f}$ is continuous, the image of $p_i\circ\hat{f}$ would be closed and open in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is connected, this would imply that $p_i\circ\hat{f}$ is surjective. This contradicts the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is not compact. We conclude that $\hat{f}$, and consequently $f$, is constant.

Comment: +1, nice! A more general statement is demonstrated in Hatcher (the lifting theorem) (it doesn't require Hausdorff)

Comment: What do you mean by "Open Mapping Theorem for multivariate holomorphic functions"? E.g. the map $\mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2, (x,y) \mapsto (x,xy)$ is holomorphic, but its image is $(\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{x = 0\}) \cup \{(0,0)\}$, which is not open.

Comment: @FShrike Skimming through Forster's proof, it seems to me that he uses the Hausdorff property to show that two liftings are the same if they agree at one point (Theorem 4.8.). The proof of Theorem 4.8 employs the fact that in a Hausdorff space the diagonal is closed. Since I did not need the uniqueness of the lifting, I dropped it from my formulation of his Theorem 4.17 (and wrote that this is 'essentially' Forster's Theorem 4.17.) Since I did not use the uniqueness part, I probably could drop the Hausdorff requirement, but will keep it just to be sure.

Comment: @red_trumpet Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I should have been more careful. Is the argument correct now? Alternatively, we could have derived a contradiction via the maximum principle, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Looks like I confused functions and maps (though the name of the theorem does not help :D)